# Not all custom button photos are showing up in Xcode simulator or device

Tags: iphone, xcode, png, simulator

I have been working on making home screen button link images for my app to take the user to different pages.  When I was finally done with making all of the custom photos (all same resolution), only two of them show up on my device/simulator and I can not for the life of me figure out why.  You can view what the storyboard vs the simulator looks like [here](http://cl.ly/image/3E1945040j3R).  It looks the exact same on my iPhone 4, and I adjusted all of the view controllers in my storyboard to be compatible with retina 3.5 inch only.  If anyone knows whats going on, I would be more than happy to hear your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: are you designing it on storyboard

Answer (score 0):

1)just strech more that means just try to increase the width & height of your images just by pulling or streching them.

2)be sure images has correct Named

3)be sure that images are added in project

Comment: I deleted the images and re-imported them and for some reason that worked.  Thanks for your help anyway!